# iPad: will my book in HTML look the same on all iPads?

Tags: html, ipad

I am working on a beautiful book for the iPad together with an artist/designer, and we would like it to look perfect.

I am using HTML to lay out the pages, and i noticed that they look slightly different in a browser, in a simulator and on the actual iPad (the paragraphs are broken into lines a bit differently, most probably because the glyphs in the fonts are rendered a bit differently).

Can i be sure that my book will look the same on all iPads? (That is if I use HTML, and not, say, PDF). Should I supply fonts together with the app, or can I rely on the system fonts? Is it better to specify the font size in pt or cm?

**UPD:** I am using UIWebViews.

Thanks in advance, 
Timofey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never quite be 100% sure that a HTML page will look the same across all browsers on all platforms, although cross browser compatibility is generally improving with each browser version - those of us who have been doing this since the days of IE6 will remember those days with a shudder!

What helps with the iPad however is that its the same device, same screen resolution and running the same software (iOS and Safari), so if you test it on an iPad in that configuration, it will look the same on all others.

However a word of caution - you can get the Firefox browser for iPad, and all software - including iOS and Safari is subject to change and upgrades, and subject to the fact that people can also be running out of date versions if they don't plug in and sync very often.

Of course, any upgrades are not guaranteed to change the HTML rendering engine, i'm just saying its possible.

The best thing to do is ensure you keep most of your styling in CSS, so that if say, iOS 5, or iPad 3 did something unexpected down the line - you can make simple edits across the whole site/book without having to edit every page of it.

Comment: There is no official version of Firefox for iOS devices (including the iPad) - just checked the App Store. There is Firefox Home for iPhone (only), but it's not really the Firefox browser itself.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As to Firefox, i am using UIWebViews (added that to the post), so i didn't think about browser compatibility at first, but then much to my surprise the same page looked a bit different in three variants of what i had thought to be the same browser. That got me worrying a bit :)

Comment: @Svilen my mistake, I had only heard of Firefox Home, and just assumed it was official and for both the iPhone and iPad.  I've never looked further into it since both the devices ship with Safari which is a perfectly good browser and i've never felt the need to find an alternative (though I do use Firefox on Windows).

Comment: @Ibolit feel free to accept the answer if you're happy with it, it keeps us happy :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS 3.0 feature, which allows you to specify a font for your web page elements, that is to make sure it looks the same on all browsers/operating systems, even if they don't have the same fonts installed:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-resources

http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/

Concerning other elements - it is CSS hacks again, you have to see what the differences are, and try deal with each problem individually, depending on the browser. iPad's are using a mobile version of Safari by default, but Opera also have a mobile browser for iOS devices.